# Why is SQLServerDriver gone from Slick 2.0.0-M3 to Slick 2.0.0?

Tags: sql-server, scala, slick

I was using Slick 2.0.0-M3 in my project and just upgraded to Slick 2.0.0

ScalaDoc (2.0.0-M3): http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0-M3/api/index.html#package

SaclaDoc (2.0.0): http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/api/#package

In the former, the SQLServerDriver Trait is available, whereas in the latter it is gone. Can someone tell me where to optain it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for non-open-source databases including SQL Server is available as part of the commercial slick-extensions offered by Typesafe. More info here: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/extensions.html

As of Slick 2.0.0, the SQL Server driver (being a non-open-source database) is not open source any more.

Comment: Can I somehow add the slick-extensions using maven?

Comment: There are published here: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases/

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.slick</groupId>
        <artifactId>slick-extensions_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: You might want to add this to your answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you may want to check [Freeslick](https://github.com/fommil/freeslick)